# Fluentd sql output plugin configuration for auto incremented column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, fluentd, td-agent

I have a fluentd configuration that pulls data from the file and pushes to the SQL server however there is a primary key with the auto-incremented column, so, in my fluentd configuration if I don't mention that column it throws an error saying that the field is missing and if I include the column in the configuration it gives identity error, in below configuration "Id" is the primary and auto-incremented column, also let me know if adapter "sqlserver" is the right thing to use.

```
<filter record.**>
      @type record_transformer
      enable_ruby  true
      <record>
        Id ${id}
      </record>
      <record>
        timestamp ${time}
      </record>
    </filter>

    <filter record.**>
      @type stdout
    </filter>

    <match record.**> 
        
        @type sql
        host myhost
        username myuser
        password mypassword
        database mydb
        adapter sqlserver

        <table>
          table simple_table
          column_mapping 'Id:Id,timestamp:timestamp'
        </table>
        
        flush_interval 1s
        # disable_retry_limit
        # num_threads 8
        # slow_flush_log_threshold 40.0
    </match>
```

Comment: Please add the error messages for both cases in the question. Also, there's no mention of such a case in the docs of [fluent-plugin-sql](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sql) output plugin (https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sql#output-how-it-works). Nor is there any special handling for this case while parsing `column_mapping` (https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sql/blob/8c3c59322a51b2bce8d9fcebdf6e9aa0598e71b3/lib/fluent/plugin/out_sql.rb#L140-L149). There is no such issue reported so far. See [issues](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sql/issues), just to be sure.

Comment: You should [open an issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sql/issues/new/choose) and report this.

Comment: @Azeem It's an issue however I figured it out what was causing the error, opening an issue in GitHub doesn't seem like someone will reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured this out, it's mandatory to send the column name in the column_mapping even though if its primary key and auto-incremented, if you login with some other SQL credential it will give you an error, however, if you login with the same details used at the time of table creation it works.